# Novice C question concerning building strings using pointers in sprintf and snprintf

Tags: c, printf

In C, if `j` is a pointer to the first position of the numerical representation of a date held in a portion of a JSON string such as `"{\"date\":1605924795664}"` held in a character array (thus, pointing to "1"), in the code below, is there a way to build the string in `sprintf` using the pointer `j` without having to first copy the date to character array `d`? Or is it best to just copy it and use it in the `sprintf` expression as is?

```
int build_schema( char *j )
  {
    char d[14];
    char sql[380] = ...expression of length 322;
    int p;
    for ( p = 0; p < 13; p++ ) { d[p] = *(j+p); }
    d[p] = '\0';
    p = 321;
    p += sprintf( sql + p, "%s,\"e\":%s,\"m\":0,\"g\":[],\"q\":[]}');", d, d );
    /* ... */
    return 0;
  }
```

I tried this using `snprintf` and the pointer only without copying. It worked in litte tests when `j` was of length `13` not counting the `\0`; but when `j` points to the address of a character in the midst of a string with more than `13` characters remaining, `snprintf` returns `-1` instead of `13`. I'm using the GCC compiler.

```
p += snprintf( sql + p, 13, "%s", j );  
p += sprintf( sql + p, "%s", ",\"e\":" );
p += snprintf( sql + p, 13, "%s", j );
p += sprintf( sql + p, "%s", ",\"m\":0,\"g\":[],\"q\":[]}');" );
```

I don't understand that.  I thought `-1` was returned only if there wasn't enough space in `sql` to hold the additional `13` characters, not if `j` was larger than `13`. Would you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

---

Here is the test code I ran. Thanks.

When `*j` is `"1605924795664"` the values of `p` are: 334, 339, 352, 376.

When `*j` is `"1605924795664 abc"` the values of `p` are: 320, 325, 324, 348.

Note that `p` starts of at 321. You can see that it decreases by 1 after each attempt to write `j` when `*j` is longer than `13`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void build_schema( char * );
char *j = "1605924795664 abc";
int main( void )
 { build_schema( j ); return 0; }

void build_schema( char *j )
  {
    int p = 321;
    char sql[ 380 ] = "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;"
                      "create table maps( key integer primary key, portfolio integer, module integer, tab integer, page integer, map text );"
                      "create table media( key integer primary key, note text, entry integer, data text );"
                      "create table tags( key integer primary key, desc text );"
                      "insert into maps values(NULL,0,0,0,0,'{\"k\":1,\"c\":'"; // Length 326 (less four '\' escape characters) = 322.

    p += snprintf( sql + p, 13, "%s", j );  
    printf( "p : %d\nsql: %s\n", p, sql );
    p += sprintf( sql + p, "%s", ",\"e\":" );
    printf( "p : %d\nsql: %s\n", p, sql );
    p += snprintf( sql + p, 13, "%s", j );
    printf( "p : %d\nsql: %s\n", p, sql );
    p += sprintf( sql + p, "%s", ",\"m\":0,\"g\":[],\"q\":[]}');" );
    printf( "p : %d\nsql: %s\n", p, sql );
  }
```

---

I learned some important things through this question. Following the answer from @dxiv, the full expression I was trying to build can be done as:

```
q = snprintf( sql + p,          
              sizeof(sql) - p,  
              "%.*s%s%.*s%s",   
              len, j,
              ",\"e\":",
              len, j, 
              ",\"m\":0,\"g\":[],\"q\":[]}" );
```

Regarding the difference in the return value, apparently the minGW-W64 bug issue is still present or it uses the glibc 2.0.6 version or earlier, I don't know, but there is a note that `Until glibc 2.0.6, they would return -1.`

Interesting though, if the expression above for `q` is used, and the size of `sql` reduced to `370` to cause a truncation, the result of

```
printf( "q: %d, p: %d, sizeof(sql): %d, sizeof(sql)-p-1: %d\n", q, p, sizeof(sql), sizeof(sql)-p-1 );
```

is `q: -1, p: 321, sizeof(sql): 370, sizeof(sql)-p-1: 48`

yet the expression `if ( q > sizeof(sql) - p - 1 )` evaluates to `true` and the error message of `*** error: -1 char string too long` is printed.

So, I don't understand what is going on concerning the return value in minGW-W64 when run out of space, for it prints `-1` but evaluates to greater than `48`.

Regardless, this answers my question and solves my problem. To be safe, the test on `q` could be modified to include `q < 0`.

Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: The second block of code doesn't work except when `j` has length `13`, as described in paragraph above it. The first `snprintf` returns `-1` in that case. So, it backs up one space and overwrites that portion of the string.

Comment: The `snprintf` calls will write 12 characters to the string plus the nul terminator, but the return value will be (or at least is supposed to be) 14 which is the string length of `"1605924795664}"` that would have been printed ignoring the size `13` argument.

Comment: [ man 3 snprintf ](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) `"If the output was truncated due to this limit, then the return value is the number of characters (excluding the terminating null byte) which would have been written to the final string if enough space had been available."`

Comment: Thank you. I read that also. Enough space where? In `sql`? There is more than enough space there to hold the characters.  If it means that there are more than 13 characters in `j`, I still don't get it.  Either way it is returning `-1`, such that the second `snprintf` writes on top of the `:` after the `"c"`. Perhaps, I'm doing something else wrong.

Comment: @Gary `it is returning -1` Check the return value, it's most likely `14` not `-1`. What happens is that your result string will have "gaps" like `"160592479566\0\0,\"e\": ..."`. When used as a nul terminated C string it will appear to have length `12`.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you.  I can see that it is returning `-1` for two reasons.  I print out the value of `p` after each step and it decreases by one after each `snprintf` that involves `j` and I can see that there are no gaps in the string but instead the next lines overwrite the previous character.  I'm not trying to argue and appreciate the help but that is what is happening. I'll add the sample code I've been running in GCC.

Comment: @Gary Sample `gcc` compile posted as an answer. See the [snprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) documentation why the return value must be 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying the original code to just the first `snprintf` + `sprintf`:

```
int build_schema( char *j )
  {
    printf("j = '%s', strlen(j) = %zu\n", j, strlen(j));

    char sql[380];
    int p = 321, q;

    memset(sql, '_', sizeof(sql));

    q = snprintf( sql + p, 13, "%s", j );  // <-- writes 12 chars + nul terminator
                                           //     returns 14 == strlen(j)
    printf("snprintf = %d\n", q);
    p += q;
    p += sprintf( sql + p, "%s", ",\"e\":" );

    printf("sql + 321 = '%s\\%d%c%s'\n", sql + 321, (sql + 321)[12], (sql + 321)[13], sql + 321 + 14);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char json[] = "{\"date\":1605924795664}";
    build_schema(json + 8);
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/h8rPT5), with explanations inserted below:

```
j = '1605924795664}', strlen(j) = 14
snprintf = 14
sql + 321 = '160592479566\0_,"e":'

             ^          ^ ^^^
             |          | |||
     sql + 321          | |||
                        | |||
   12 chars from snprintf |||
                          |||
   nul term from snprintf |||
                           ||
    '_' left from sql buffer|
                            |
         5 chars from sprintf
```

Fixed code:

```
int build_schema( char *j )
  {
    char sql[380];
    int p = 321, q;

    snprintf( sql + p, 14, "%s", j );  
    p += 13;
    p += sprintf( sql + p, "%s", ",\"e\":" );

    printf("sql + 321 = '%s'\n", sql + 321);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char json[] = "{\"date\":1605924795664}";
    build_schema(json + 8);
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/35jr71):

```
sql + 321 = '1605924795664,"e":'
```

---

[ ***EDIT*** ]   The above explains the issue, and the "*fixed code*" shows the minimal change to fix it. However, it does not address the root cause of the problem, which is (mis)using the `bufsize` parameter of [snprintf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to control the width of a string argument.

Instead, `bufsize` should be used the way it was meant to, for preventing buffer overruns, and the string width should be controlled with the [`"%.*s` syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for the precision specifier. Sample such code below, with the same correct `1605924795664,"e":` [output](https://godbolt.org/z/Ebc4vT).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int build_schema( char *j, int len )
  {
    char sql[380];
    int p = 321, q;

    q = snprintf( sql + p,          // write to `sql` buffer starting at offset 321
                  sizeof(sql) - p,  // 59 chars left in buffer, do not overrun
                  "%.*s%s",         // write 'len' chars from 'j', then 2nd string
                  len, j,
                  ",\"e\":" );  

    if( q > sizeof(sql) - p - 1)
    {
        printf("*** error: %d char string too long\n", q);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("sql + 321 = '%s'\n", sql + 321);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char json[] = "{\"date\":1605924795664}";
    build_schema(json + 8,  // string starting at `1`
                 13);       // excluding the trailing `}`
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know what is wrong on my end but if I run your first block of code exactly as is, the second line prints the value of `snprintf` as `-1` and not `14` and the next line starts with`'"e":\52`` and then some control characters or some gibberish. Does it matter that I'm using minGW-W64? Overall, I guess it doesn't matter since the solution is going to be to not rely on the return value when dealing with pointer `j` and explicitly set `p` afterward. I can do that. I just don't understand the return value or, now, why using 13 results in the correct string on my end.

Comment: @Gary If your `snprintf` returns `-1` with this code then either the CRT library is non compliant or there is some problem hidden elsewhere in the code not posted here.

Comment: I don't know. I ran the code in your answer just as is apart from adding in the stdio.h and string.h headers. I didnt' add it into the rest of my code to get that result. Strange. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: @Gary The updated code in your question [overruns the `sql` buffer](https://godbolt.org/z/PWs9E4) at the last `sprintf` (presumably because of miscounting those "gaps"). After that it's [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) and all bets are off.

Comment: I'm confused by that.  The value of `p` is 376 when `j` is exactly the desired string and 348 when it includes the extra " abc". `sql` is declared as length 380. How do you know it overflows? Plus, the first block of code that copies the date and builds the string with `sprintf` works fine and all components are the same size. I could be wrong, of course, I just don't follow. Thanks.

Comment: Probably because when `j` includes the " abc" my side is returning `-1` and yours `14`. That why. I'll make it 1000 and see it maks a difference.

Comment: @Gary The [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PWs9E4) link in my previous comment shows `p : 360` before the last `sprintf`, then you write 25 more characters to it but `360 + 25 + 1 > 380`.

Comment: I'm sorry I overlooked the link and just looked at it now.  I see what you mean but my run has lower numbers because of the `-1`.  Nonetheless, I ran it at sql[1000] and I get the same results, with the return value of `-1`. Do you think it could be because godbolt is compiling it as C++ that the return values are different?

Comment: I tried it in godbolt as C with sql[1000] and it gives your results. I do not know why when I use the GCC MinGW-W64 to compile, I get the results I provided, even after adding the extra buffer space.

Comment: @Gary Did you overlook the links in my answer, too? They are all compiled as C because of the `-x c` switch. Which is the first line that's different on your machine vs. godbolt? If it's after the UB then it doesn't count. Otherwise, if the exact same code gives different output on your machine then there is a problem with your compiler/environment and no one will be able to help without knowing how to duplicate it. Also, just increasing the buffer size without fixing the miscount is not going to fix anything.

Comment: I apologize, I did miss them. Thanks for all your help.  I'll have to reinstall the compiler and see what happens.  I'm far from a knowledgeable C programmer but I know enough to read the results of this little sample. So, I don't know what else to do than reinstall it. Even when I use th elink in your answer and change j to the exact string, the results differ.

Comment: This may be the reason https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/709/ for the differences is results.

Comment: Thank you. The edit you made works in my compiler also because it avoids the difference completely. I didn't understand `bufsz` at all and was using it as the number of characters I wanted to write from the second string. Thanks for showing me the right way.

Comment: If you don't mind, would you tell me one more thing on this? Is using `snprintf` like this more efficient than just copying the date and using `sprintf`? Is `snprintf` going to use more memory to do what it does to build the string than usinig `sprintf`? Being a beginner, I wanted to use pointers and not use memory to copy a string but didn't consider the memory used by the library functions. I may just be complicating the simple. Thanks.

Comment: @Gary `snprintf` has no seizable overhead compared to `sprintf`. Both are made precisely for the kind of manipulations you have, but being general purpose they are not necessarily the most "*efficient*" in any particular case vs. custom code hand-crafted for (and only for) that particular case. However, this falls under micro-optimization which should never be the first concern. Ease of use and clarity of code most often trump ultimate "performance". When in doubt, measure the timings and measure again before deciding it's a real bottleneck worth micro-optimizing.